# Netregistry doesn't allow AWS ACM cname validation records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, cname

I need to verify the ownership of the domain to validate the SSL certificate of the domain.

When I try to add the ACM CNAME validation records, I get an error from Netregistry console.

```
_*****109831*****.t*****k.acm-validations.aws is an invalid hostname
```

I read that the _ is a valid char in the DNS label

`An underscore can appear in any place in a DNS label.`

Any workaround to get rid of this problem

Comment: Netregistry doesn't support that kind of cname. you need to look for a better DNS manager

Comment: "_ is a valid char in the DNS label" yes, for domain names, not hostnames. Make sure you use a CNAME, as for it both the owner and data are domain names so the underscore is legit. Note however that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @KmoSkillz check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this.

remove the '_' from the cname name and just leave it in the value

AWS can still validate the SSL Certificate in case '_' is missing from name.

Netregistry won't complain about '_' in the value. it will complain only for name

Comment: Awesome stuff. Thanks mate.

Comment: Actually, the AWS documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-DNS-validation.html says you can remove the underscore from the VALUE, but not from the NAME.